# Hard private state in C++

Tags: c++, private, integrity

Assuming the platform doesn't expose another means of peeking at memory locations (I know C++ is usually compiled to actual machine code), is it possible, the way it is in e.g. JavaScript?

I know there are utilities such as `memcpy` and `bit_cast`. They work, IIUC, on any data that the language syntax or the standard library can produce. But would it be compliant with the C++ standard for an implementation to provide custom types, or perhaps a facility working with normal types (like an exotic Allocator), to whose members some values can be assigned and yet nothing the programmer could write (or `#include`, even coming from an untrusted source) would be able to read them in an uncontrolled manner?

Comment: Would you expect this implementation to provide such a guarantee even in the presence of (otherwise) undefined behavior?

Comment: No, UB means, per the standard, that anything can happen. Yea, to make it practical, either the implementation would have to document all its UB or compiler warnings (and possibly additional tools) of UB would have to be turned on and heeded. Detecting UB in general is impossible (would make the halting problem decidable), so a restriction (preferably syntactical) to a subset of C++ would also be necessary.

Comment: This sort of requirement usually requires custom hardware to implement properly (e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_Platform_Module ); without that, anyone with a good debugger has access to anything you do, and the best you can do is slow them down a little with layers of obfuscation.

Comment: Nothing can stop the kernel from reading memory, so the answer to your question must be "no"

Comment: Are you asking "How can I sandbox my application to prevent it from being debugged?"

Comment: **What are you really trying to do?**.  Your title is "Hard private state", but I think you really mean "Hide private state". In any case, it sounds like you are trying to secure something in memory that you wouldn't want someone getting at.  There's classic obfuscation techniques, "secure buffers", to using the TPM as another commenter above suggested. The depth that you need to go to depends on the value of the data you need to protect. Protecting someone from hacking a video game doesn't require the same level as a financial application. What is it that needs protecting?

Comment: @tadman, no, if run in debug mode, during development. selbie, could be that, though I'm thinking in terms of more familiar to me virtual ISAs (e.g. WebAssembly, Low Level Virtual Machine, Ethereum Virtual Machine).

Comment: The title of this question is misleading. It should be **Hide private state**. You seem to want your users not to be able to read certain pieces of memory when running their applications within yours which is probably a sandbox environment for users just like [JavaScript in the Browser.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandbox_(computer_security)#Implementations)

Comment: @ByteEater "implementation" includes VM and OS the program is run on, three are garbage-collecting VM C++ implementations. UB doesn't mean it be undetectable, it means that standard neither got requirements of any guarantees nor requires implementation to document the behaviour. But implementation MAY have guarantees. There are VM-based C++. e.g. Portland Group one with leak detection, garbage-clllecting C++s and there are data race condition-negating ones.

Comment: Would this private state even be inaccessible to the debugger?  Would this private state even be hidden from a memory dump of the process?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that would be legal. Undefined Behavior may include behaving in a way that's typical or documented for a given environment. Hence, your proposed C++ extension should be designed in such a way that using them is UB according to the Standard, but still documented by the implementation.